# Администрирование android устройств

Tags: android, администрирование

Подскажите системы администрирования андроид устройств. Есть парк около 20 планшетов, существуют ли готовые решения для администрирования(платные, бесплатные). Также главный нюанс в том, что устройства будут находится в зоне с плохим сигналом и ограниченным объемом трафика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гуглить "mobile device management"
Решения есть. 
Вот [неплохой списочек](https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/enterprise-mobility-management-suites). На отзывы в списке не ориентируйтесь сильно - понятия не имею кто поставил такую высокую оценку решению от Каспера (видел вживую - там всё очень печально)

Для 20 планшетов практически всё из этого списка неоправданно дорого.
Рынок таких продуктов молодой отсюда куцый функционал и плохая совместимость с устройствами разных вендоров.

С учётом ваших объемов взгляните для начала на [управление от google](https://gsuite.google.com/products/admin/) возможно этого будет достаточно.